# Convert an integer range to a list of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert a range of integers to a list of strings using LINQ?

For example, for a range of integers 1-12, the expected result would be "01", "02", "03", ..., "12".

The approach that I came up with incrementally builds a `List<string>`. Is there a more succinct way to get my desired result?

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
var numberList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    string mth = (item.ToString().Length == 1)
        ? "0" + item.ToString()
        : item.ToString();

    numberList.Add(mth);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Edit- What I mean is, that is perfectly clear, switching to a lambda driven aggregate can only hurt readability no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ToString can do this for you:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(n => n.ToString("00"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `string.Join()` and `Where()`:

```
var numers = numbers
   .Where(n => n > 5)
   .Select(n => String.Format("\"{0}\"", n));
var str = String.Join(numbers, ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberList = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString());
```